# Oracle Table Size without Data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to have a table that reports a size but does not have any rows in it? When I run the following query one of the tables reports a size but does not contain any rows. How is this possible?

```
select table_name, 
       b.tablespace_name,
       sum( bytes)/1024/1024 "SIZE IN MB" 
  from USER_segments a,
       user_tables b 
  where table_name=segment_name 
  group by segment_name,
        b.tablespace_name,
        table_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table segements grow when data is inserted into them. Since 11g a new created table can be created without a segment. When data is inserted into such a newly created table, the segment is created.

The space that is occupied by the segment is not automatically returned to the free space in the datafile when rows are deleted. So, your table is created empty with direct segment creation, or it had rows and they are deleted.

Comment: Or, if it's a brand-new table, or rows have been deleted using `truncate`(not `delete` - won't return space) statement, the query can simply report the initial size of an extent set upon tablespace creation using `uniform size` clause of the `create tablespace` statement. If the `uniform size` clause has been omitted or `autoallocate` clause has been used instead the initial extent size would be determined by Oracle, with 64K being its minimum size.